# How to use Jquery .prevAll() with .prependTo()?

Tags: jquery

I've tried this:

```
$('li.jplayer_playlist_current').prevAll().prependTo($('#jplayer_playlist ol'));
```

With no luck, any idea what is being done wrong?

On Jquery they show this:

```
$('li.third-item').prevAll().css('background-color', 'red');
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="jplayer_playlist">
    <ol>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li class="jplayer_playlist_current">Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML?

Comment: What is the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working exactly as it should. It's removing all those list items, then re-inserting them at the exact same location!

---

If what you want is for them to be at the *end* of the `ol`, then use [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

```
$('.jplayer_playlist_current').prevAll().appendTo('#jplayer_playlist ol');
```

Comment: wow, I feel dumb. Had the prependTo above and copied and pasted. Thanks!